# What are there to reference for mymove?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to the CSS3 style. I have seen this in some of the web pages that I have been working on. Do you have to have the @-webkit-keyframes for both webkit and keyframes. Both of the functions look to have the same name so i am wondering why they are both needed. Is one used for the portable world.

Code Here:

```
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: 200px;}
}

@keyframes mymove {
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: 200px;}
}
```

So in the following case the @-webkit-keyframes is used for google and safari and @-moz-keyframes is used for firefox and then the @keyframes is just a regular statement (all browsers when there is no fade in)

Is the .myClass can be used for all. -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn is that just like the others with a default fadeIn. or is it the same as the above because of the webkit-animation-name and then the -moz-animation-name and then just a regular animation-name for all of the fadeIn.

More helpful code:

```
/* use of keyframes */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 0; }
}

/* use of basic properties */
.myClass {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
    -moz-animation-name:    fadeIn;
    animation-name:         fadeIn;
}
```

Comment: See: [CSS Vendor Prefixes](http://davidwalsh.name/vendor-prefixes) for the general answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `-webkit-` piece is called a vendor prefix. It's for webkit based browsers ('Chrome' and Safari, for example)

Vendor prefixes are usually used when the feature you're using is not yet a established standard thus are available only in few or only one browser.

Usually browser vendors release new features first with vendor prefix so web developers can starting using it until the standards consolidates and is well established, then the vendor releases a new version with the feature unprefixed (which is the second keyframe statement you have).

Your code is already prepared for when the browsers start to accept the unprefixed version, that's why you have it twice on your code.

Comment: So if a person was not worried about the vendor prefix he could just use the code that does not perfix anything, correct. We does one get this information of new developments.

Comment: Yes, you could use it, but sometimes the browser only understands the prefixed version because they're still testing the feature. There is no rule which applies to all browser it depends on the browser and on the specific feature.

Comment: Is google the best broswer. That is the one that I am making all of my test pages work in. It is just for my home use and fun so it only has to work in that specific broswer.